# dynamic variable in jsx html tag not updating

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I tried to find the reason for this weird behavior where the useState-variable in a html tag was not updating the jsx-markup text:

```
<h1>Focuscam = {topPrediction}</h1>

    <button onClick={() => setFocusCamOn(!focusCamOn)}  
            {focusCamOn ? "Turn Detection Off" : "Turn Detection On"}
    </button>

    <h2>You have been distracted for {distractionDuration} Seconds</h2>

...
```

This happened to both the variable in h1 and h2 (topPrediction and distractionDuration).

When I changed it to:

```
<p>Focuscam = {topPrediction}</p>

    <button onClick={() => setFocusCamOn(!focusCamOn)}  
            {focusCamOn ? "Turn Detection Off" : "Turn Detection On"}
    </button>

    <p>You have been distracted for {distractionDuration} Seconds</p>

...
```

everything was working. Just the styling/fontsize was off.

**Summarizing**: Why is this happening and how can I make it work without changing the HTML language.

The app is deployed at https://focuscam.netlify.app/ and the code is at https://github.com/moritzWa/focuscam.

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example?

Comment: Yes, I just deployed it at https://focuscam.netlify.app/ and the code is at https://github.com/moritzWa/focuscam.

Answer (score 0):

In the useEffect dependency array of this entire components, adding `focusCamOn, distractionDuration`, or other variables displayed in the markup solves the issue.

```
useEffect(() => {...}, [focusCamOn,distractionDuration])
```